Concerning the variations of different Tanakh versions of Second Temple and Masoretic Text authenticity
When we cross-examine the three main earliest textual variants of Tanakh in the face of Qumran Texts, Septuagint and Samaritan texts, we find a plethora (of mostly minor) differences. While I am not concerned with differences of writing down a Vav or a Yud where it would normally not be written down today, or a scribe writing the lower part of Mem slightly longer, making it seem like Mem Sophit, I am concerned that there are specific variations that are slightly more concerning.
While Qumran texts on majority agree with Masoretic texts, there still seems to be among what we find a soup of slight variations that mix on how they relate to each other. Some parts of Qumran are closer to the Septuagint, some to the Masoretic and the same can be said about the cross-relations of different sets of those texts.
My question is, how does that co-exist with the idea of not a single letter being changed in Torah that we have today? What is the source of our confidence that the Masoretic text is the representation of unchanged original? Why were the textual small differences so prelevant? What does the talmudic and oral tradition say about the formation of the Tanakh canon and form that might point us to some explanations?

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Soferim.6.4?lang=bi

This is interesting, but also does it mean that this practice was not followed by everyone? Seeing as there are many variants in Dead Sea Scrolls and Septugiant probably getting it's translation from perhaps an unknown Hebrew source that does not fully agree with Masoretic?

From a religious point of view: The Jews of Qumran were not part of Rabbinic Judaism, most consider them heretics. So they could have their own versions which we don't consider authentic.

That I do understand, but something that still slightly leaves questions is why there is potential similarity between Qumran texts and Septugiant. Even if they are not as major as Masoretic texts, why do specific misspellings and differences are also attested in Septugiant? Could Septugiant have been translated through those unauthoritative versions?

You're missing a few important points. Qumran scrolls cover a wide time period, and some of their scrolls are closer to the Masoretic text, others are somewhat different. Considering translations used by Christians, the Septuagint had a different Hebrew original (Vorlage), while the Vulgate used the Masoretic text. Even in contemporary printed books you'll find typos, how the more so in copied manuscripts. Rabbinic Judaism developed a method to avoid such errors, and we maintain that Torah we have now is the one the Moses received at Mount Sinai. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/136389
